# How to sample simultaneously from two columns in R?

Tags: r, loops, datatable, lapply

I am trying to draw samples `param1` and `param2` from `df_sample` to  `df`. I tried to use the setDT function as suggested elsewhere, to input two columns..but the output only recognizes the first `param1`. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

NOTE: The param1 and param2 values should be sampled independently.
For e.g., in site 1 quad 1, it is either the 5.57 and 499.04 pair OR 3.56 and 499.37 pair..but ideally those could be swapped as well. So I'm looking to sample param1 and param2 independently.

```
#DATA FRAMES
set.seed(501)
month <- rep(c("J","J","J","F","M"), each = 5)
site <- rep(c("1","2","3","1","2"), each = 5)
quad <- rep(c("1","2","3","4","5"), rep = 5)

df <- data.frame(month,site,quad)

site <- rep(c("1","2","3"), each = 20)
quad <- c("1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","2","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","2","3","4","5","1","1","3","4","5","1","1","3","4","5")
param1 <- rnorm(60,5,1)
param2 <- rnorm(60,500,1)

df_sample <- data.frame(site,quad, param1, param2)

library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df <- setDT(df_sample)[,list(param=list(param1, param2)),by=list(site,quad)][
  setDT(df),
  on = c("site","quad")][,param:=sapply(param, sample, 1)][]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 or above needed for `.by`
set.seed(1)
df_sample <- 
  df_sample %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number(), 
         max = max(id), .by = c(site, quad))

df %>% 
  left_join(distinct(df_sample, site, quad, max)) %>% 
  mutate(id = sapply(max, sample, size = 1)) %>% 
  left_join(df_sample)
```

```r
   month site quad max id   param1   param2
1      J    1    1   4  1 5.577281 499.0493
2      J    1    2   4  4 4.813692 499.5953
3      J    1    3   4  3 5.237906 500.0975
4      J    1    4   4  1 5.225781 500.9566
5      J    1    5   4  2 6.223762 501.5960
6      J    2    1   3  1 6.151618 500.9271
7      J    2    2   5  3 5.622492 499.7996
8      J    2    3   4  2 4.479705 501.0895
9      J    2    4   4  2 3.680826 500.7056
10     J    2    5   4  3 6.491763 498.2079
11     J    3    1   6  3 6.708715 498.4764
12     J    3    2   2  1 5.360314 499.2427
13     J    3    3   4  1 6.091806 499.8522
14     J    3    4   4  1 5.515952 500.7180
15     J    3    5   4  2 7.633465 499.8845
16     F    1    1   4  2 3.566631 499.3791
17     F    1    2   4  2 3.351793 500.1388
18     F    1    3   4  2 5.035623 500.4443
19     F    1    4   4  3 5.465357 499.9017
20     F    1    5   4  1 4.155195 501.7882
21     M    2    1   3  3 5.519431 499.2223
22     M    2    2   5  5 4.725804 500.7145
23     M    2    3   4  1 5.151815 499.6472
24     M    2    4   4  1 5.455574 500.3809
25     M    2    5   4  1 4.721432 499.4773
```

Comment: This has been super helpful! I can't help notice though that the values for `param1` and `param2` are always linked for a given site and quad. For e.g., in site 1 quad 1, it is either the 5.57 and 499.04 pair OR 3.56 and 499.37 pair..but ideally those could be swapped as well. So I'm looking to sample param1 and param2 independently. How can I do this?